# Find the minimum and maximum element of 5 different elements in C++

Tags: c++

Need to take out the highest and lowest numbers of 5 judges 0 to 10 on the score

cout << "Please enter the name of the athelete.\n";

```
            getline(cin, name);


            cin >> name;

            cout << "Please enter the first judge's score below\n";


            cout << "Please enter a score between 0 and 10.\n";

            cin >> First_Score;
```

Comment: You probably should use an array instead of 5 variables. Maybe std::array<int,5> myArray;

Comment: Do you know about loops and vector/arrays?

Comment: The easiest solution will likely be to make two passes over the scores; one to find the indices of the min/max element, and then one to calculate the sum (skipping those two elements you found in pass #1).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have recently learned about loops, arrays and sorting.

Comment: I hate ambiguous questions. It isn't clear to me whether you should drop all of the highest or lowest scores or just one of each. For instance if the set of 5 was 2 2 3 5 5 would the answer be 3 or 3.3333... Or perhaps the problem presumes there is only one of each?

Comment: Just as a heads up we cannot use arrays and functions per the teachers instructions :\ Reasons I had to lay it out like this. Please don't shun me for this I'm still very new to this all lmao

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is a forum, where you go to discuss an exercise that you have difficulties with. Apart from the exercise (too bad you initially forgot the constraint of "no array"), the question is useless. Consider making a study group with your peers.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code

```
loop for 5 answers
sort them
sum of middle 3 
avg sum / 3
print
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to create two additional variables. The first, 'lowest', to store the lowest value and the second, 'biggest' to store the biggest value.

```
int lowest = 0, biggest = 11;
...
cin >> First_Score;
            while (First_Score < 0 || First_Score > 10)
            {
                cout << "That is not a valid input, please pick between 0 and 10.\n";
                cin >> First_Score;
                cout << "Your selection was " << First_Score << endl;
            }
lowest = First_Score;
biggest = First_Score;
...
```

And then for each judge :

```
 cout << "Please enter the fifth judge's score here below\n";
            cin >> Fifth_Score;

            while (Fifth_Score < 0 || Fifth_Score > 10)
            {
                cout << "That is not a valid input, please pick between 0 and 10.\n";
                cin >> Fifth_Score;
                cout << "Your selection was " << Fifth_Score << endl;
            }
if(lowest > Fifth_Score)
 lowest = Fifth_Score;
if(biggest < Fifth_Score)
 biggest = Fifth_Score;
...

int sum = Avg_Score = (First_Score + Second_Score + Third_Score + Fourth_Score + Fifth_Score);
Avg_Score = (sum - lowest - biggest) / 3;
...
```

Comment: this is exactly what the teacher is looking for because we cannot use arrays and functions until later on in the class sadly,  but thank you for the advice and help c:

Answer (score 0):

Always separate input and logic.

```
#include <vector>  // std::vector
#include <numeric> // std::sort, std::accumulate
#include <cassert> // assert

auto score(std::vector<double> scores) {
    assert(scores.size()>2);
    auto n = scores.size() - 2;
    // sort ...
    // sum ...
    return sum / n;
}

int main() {
    assert(score({1,5,9}) == 5);
    assert(score({5,5,5}) == 5);
    assert(score({0,5,0}) == 0);
    assert(score({1,2,3,4,5,6}) == 3);
}
```

I left the actual implementation for you. My implementation fits in three lines.

I hope this inspires you to get a clean implemntation, that you can easily use to write the rest of the program with.

Comment: Its not as messy looking on visual studios i promise LOL but here is a little obstacle we cannot use  arrays or functions. per the teachers instructions :\

Comment: I wasn't saying anything about the looks. I was talking about the code organization. And yeah, if you cannot use functions it's gonna be hard to achieve good code organization. You're effectively handicapped then.

Comment: 100% handicapped... Even worse when it seems as tho getting a straight answer from her is a chore. Havent asked but have been looking at others asking. Figured I would try my luck on some forums

Comment: Seriously, I wouldn't know how to properly code this while handicapped. What's more, what's the point? I'd ditch the course, but I'm afraid that might not be a good option. So sorry.

Comment: LOL it’s doable but yeah my brother who codes told me do an array and when I said I couldn’t he just shook his head lmao it’s a prerequisite for a java class so I’m pretty much forced into taking this class unfortunately